# there is no distance- regular graph with intersection array $\left \{ 3, 2, 1; 1,1, 3 \right \}$.

Tags: algebraic-graph-theory

By finding an appropriate eigenvector, show that there is no distance- 
regular graph with intersection array $\left \{ 3, 2, 1; 1,1, 3 \right \}$.

can you little help me how should I make an eigenvector for the cause,and after I make this,what is its relation with intersection array?

I am confused about this,

any hint or Idea will be great ,thanks.

this is exercise 3.17 page 101 of An Introduction to the Theory of Graph Spectra DRAGOS CVETKOVIC and PETER ROWLINSON and there is no more detailes.

Comment: I don't really understand the task. I can show that the spectrum determined by the given intersection array contains irrational numbers (roots of $x^4-x^3-8x^2+3x+9=0$). If I create eigenvectors to these irrational eigenvalues I can see the non-existence, but it was already visible from the spectrum. So please add more details, how to interpret your question.

Comment: this is exercise 3.17 page 101 of An Introduction to the Theory of Graph Spectra DRAGOS CVETKOVIC and PETER ROWLINSON and there is no more detailes.

Comment: @ Stefan Gyürki ,can you tell me how you achieve $x^4-x^3-8x^2+3x+9=0$?

Comment: @Stefan Gyürki,thank you so much,I got it,and I compute all eigenvalue and eigenvector,I am agree with you,there is no need to eigenvector,spectrum is enough.

Comment: Should I explain you how to get that polynomial?

Comment: no thanks,I got it.